# CSS Media query with hover and screen size

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm writing a CSS Media Query and I want 3 styles: one for all mobile devices, one for desktops with low resolution screens, and one for desktop with high resolution screens. I tried with the hover query to sort out mobile devices and added the screen height to test for desktop monitors.

This works well for desktop style selection but the problem is that on my Samsung cellphone with div is green instead of the expected blue.

Here's the test: what can I do to get the expected results?

```css
        @media (hover: hover) and (max-height: 999px) {
            div {background:green;}
        }

        @media (hover: hover) and (min-height: 1000px) { 
            div {background:red;}
        }

        @media (hover: none) {
            div {background:blue;}
        }
```

```html
<div style="width:200px;height:200px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
        @media (hover: hover) and (min-width: 787px) {
            div {background:green;}
        }

        @media (hover: hover) and (min-width: 1000px) { 
            div {background:red;}
        }

        @media (hover: hover) and (max-width: 786px) {
            div {background:blue;}
        }
```

```html
<div style="width:200px;height:200px;"></div>
```

Comment: I've already got a resolution-based solution but it doesn't work because there are mobile devices which have higher resolutions than desktops, hence my wanting to use the hover:none query to differentiate devices.